# Getting error 200 Ok in the below code

Tags: integration

Hi i am trying to integrate the 3rd party resume parser in salesforce i have written the below code. Please let me know what i am doing wrong.

```
Http http = new Http();

HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

request.setEndpoint('http://example.com');

List <attachment> doc = [select body,name from attachment where Id='xxxxxxx'];
attachment doc1=doc[0];
String File= doc1.name;
Blob bodyblob = doc1.Body;
String bodystr=EncodingUtil.base64Encode(bodyblob);
String Userkey='xxxxxxxxx';
String Version='xxx';
String subU='xxxxxxxxxx';

request.setMethod('POST');

request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

request.setbody('{"filedata":'+bodystr+',"filename":'+File+',Userkey="xxxxxx","version":"xxx","subuserid":"xxxxxxxx"}');

HttpResponse response = http.send(request);


if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {

    System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +

        response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
System.debug(response.getBody());

} else {

    System.debug(response.getBody());

}
```

The format send should be 
JSON Request Format:
{ "filedata": " File data in base64 ",
"filename": "File name with extension", "userkey": "Your User key", "version": "version",
"subuserid": "subuserid"
}

Comment: 200 isn't an error. Please check your documentation.

Comment: but the body is not getting any data its blank

Answer (score 0):

200 is a good status, not an error status. That said, it looks like Userkey should be userkey (note the capital U is incorrect). Always make sure you're paying attention to capitalization when working with APIs.

Comment: now i have updated the userkey word now getting 404 not found error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this:

```
 String str = JSON.serialize('{"filedata":'+bodystr+',"filename":'+File+',Userkey="xxxxxx","version":"xxx","subuserid":"xxxxxxxx"}');

 request.setbody(str);
```

For more information, you may refer to the [JSON class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm).